# Broadcastreceiver that should be triggered by an alarm remains untriggered

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo, android-alarms

I wanted to set alarms that played audio files. Yet they don't, according to the log, the alarms are not executed. This is my code:

```
<manifest  ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
    <application
      ...>
        <service android:name=".S1" />
        <activity
            ...>
        ...
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".A1" >
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".A2">
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and

```
public class S1 extends Service {  

    public void al(Class Klasse, long Wann)
    {
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), Klasse);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Wann, pendingIntent);
        Log.i("Debug","Alarm");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       al(A1.class,time.getTimeInMillis());
       al(A2.class,time.getTimeInMillis()+(5*1000));
       //...
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

and

```
class A1 extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //...
        Log.i("Debug","Play Audio A1");
    }
}


class A2 extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //...
        Log.i("Debug","Play Audio A2");
    }
}
```

In the logs, I see "Alarm" but neither "Play Audio A1" nor "Play Audio A2".

I am using a Huawei P20 and I followed https://dontkillmyapp.com/huawei. But they still don't fire.